# How to rebuild index in DB2 9.7 LUW

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-connect

How I can rebuild index in DB2 9.7 LUW. 
Is there any rebuild utility for index or I have to recreate index.

Regards,

Masheed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use REORG command to recreate ALL INDEXES on a table like this:

```
REORG INDEXES ALL FOR TABLE table1 ALLOW WRITE ACCESS CLEANUP ALL RECLAIM EXTENTS
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no index rebuild utility in DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows.  You just have to drop / recreate the index.

Comment: What about `REORG`? (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005407.html?lang=en)

Comment: You can't use `REORG` for a *single* index unless you have a range-partitioned table; you can only use it for *all* indexes on a table, which is not what I think the OP was asking for.

Comment: Actually you can, REORG INDEX command does that (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001966.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-4-96)

Comment: @RamazanPOLAT As I mentioned in my previous comment, `REORG INDEX` can only be used to reorg a single index when you have a partitioned table.  (and the page you link to says exactly this).